# Combine Different Date and Time Column to make one Column with Date/Time format in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqldatatypes

I am working with database in which I have appointment table. With Two columns

```
ApptDate ApptTime
9/26/21  9:00 AM
9/25/20  1:00 PM
```

I want to drop the ApptTime column after making ApptDate Columns as ApptDateTime column.
I have tried concatnate but I can't figure out, how can I change datatype of AppDate column to DATETIME data type and update all the values simultaneously.
I tried following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi'

UPDATE Appointment
SET ApptDate = ApptDate ||' ' ||ApptTime;

ALTER TABLE Appointment
MODIFY(
ApptDate DATE
);
```

But I got error that Data type can be changed of only Empty Table.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: Yeah you can't change VARCHAR2 to DATE.  You'll need to create a temporary 3rd column as DATE and assign the converted string values, then drop the ApptDate, and rename new Column to AddDate

Answer (score 0):

- ***Case 1*** : If *ApptDate* column is of string type, then recreate and populate your table as

```sql
/*CREATE TABLE Appointment( ApptDate VARCHAR2(15), ApptTime VARCHAR2(15) );

INSERT INTO Appointment
SELECT '9/26/21','9:00 AM' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '9/25/20','1:00 PM' FROM dual; -- already existing state */

CREATE TABLE Appointment2 AS
SELECT TO_DATE(ApptDate||' '||ApptTime,'MM/DD/RR HH:MI PM') AS ApptDate      
  FROM Appointment;
  
DROP TABLE Appointment;

RENAME Appointment2 TO Appointment
```

- ***Case 2*** : If data type of *ApptDate* column is ***date***, then use the following code block

```sql
/*CREATE TABLE Appointment( ApptDate DATE, ApptTime VARCHAR2(15) );

INSERT INTO Appointment
SELECT date'2021-09-26','9:00 AM' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT date'2020-09-25','1:00 PM' FROM dual; -- already existing state */

CREATE TABLE Appointment2 AS
SELECT TO_DATE(ApptDate||' '||ApptTime,'RRRR-MM-DD HH:MI PM') AS ApptDate      
  FROM Appointment;
  
DROP TABLE Appointment;

RENAME Appointment2 TO Appointment
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a49044797786f714c8a9229a6f6e3e0)</kbd>